# Access Map in property binding

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to access a value from Map and set it is a property value on the div tag but it doesn't seem to work. My syntax may not be accurate. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div [style.background-color]="bgcolor" width="50px" height="50px"> Hello Green</div>
<div [style.background-color]="bgcolors['a']" width="50px" height="50px"> Hello Red</div>
```

With in my component I have this:

```
 bgcolor= "green";
 bgcolors:  Map<string,string>;
 bgcolors = new Map<string,string>();
 bgcolors.set("a", "red");
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spalakala/3fq1cmev/13/) . First one works, second one doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below. `bgcolors.set()` function did not worked just in case. Also, to access item in Map, Use `bgcolors.get(key)` function.

```
let { Component, NgModule } = ng.core;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div [style.background-color]="bgcolor" width="50px" height="50px"> Hello Green</div>
    <div [style.background-color]="bgcolors.get('a')" width="50px" height="50px"> Hello Red</div>
  `,
})
class HomeComponent {
    bgcolor= "green";
    bgcolors:  Map<string,string>;
    bgcolors = new Map<string,string>();


    name = 'Angular 2';
    constructor() {
        this.bgcolors.set("a", "red");
    }
}

const { BrowserModule } = ng.platformBrowser;

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ HomeComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ HomeComponent ]
})
class AppModule { }

const { platformBrowserDynamic } = ng.platformBrowserDynamic;
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```